# Applescript Toggle between tabs in Safari

Tags: safari, applescript

Attempting to create automation to open a Safari browser with multiple tabs and login to common websites I use each day. I've achieved opening the browser and adding new tabs with specific URL's and prompting user for username and password but am having difficulty with simply moving between the open tabs.
I have tried assigning an index, naming the "current tab", using a title, etc. nothing seems to work... see sample below...

```
--Prompt user for login information
set GEmail to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Password" with title "Gmail" default answer "")
set GPassword to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Password" with title "Gmail" default answer "")
--Activate Safari and open new tab with URL
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    make new document with properties {URL:"https://gmail.com"}
    delay 3
    tell application "System Events"
        delay 2
        keystroke tab
        keystroke GEmail
        delay 2
        keystroke tab
        keystroke GPassword
        keystroke return
        end tell
--Create new tab pointing to Google > this does not actually open the new tab
set the URL of (make new tab in window 1) to "http://www.google.com"
end tell
```

I’ve tried multiple things but still cannot seem to actually move between the tabs and will eventually need to add several more tabs which I will need to toggle between.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you want to move between tabs? If you mean to cycle through them with the keyboard, then it is command-shift-} to make the tab to the right the current tab. If you want to create a new tab while making it current, then, open location "https://stackoverflow.com/" is one way to do so. I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve. Also, doesn't Safari have password management? Not sure what version you're using. It would likely be more secure than using applescript (but that's a guess on my part).

Answer (score 0):

To create a new **tab**, while setting focus to it, at a given **URL** use, e.g.:

```
tell application "Safari" to ¬
    tell front window to ¬
        set current tab to ¬
            (make new tab with properties {URL:"http://www.google.com"})
```